# Compresión de código con funciones en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, funciones, python3.6

Estaba realizando unos ejercicios de práctica, se nos pidió que realizaramos el código para obtener una piramide de números en la salida (desde 0 hasta un entero guardado en la variable altura) y luego se nos pidió que al código ya existente se le incluyeran funciones que sustituyeran algunas partes del código, pero la verdad no entiendo muy bien a lo que se refiere eso; ¿alguien sabe como podría incluirlas y que el código funcionara como está ahora? Este es el código:

```
altura = int(input())
contador = 0
separador = "_"
rev_contador = altura
cuant = 1
strcontadorer = contador
strcontador = str(strcontadorer)
while contador < altura:
    print(separador * (rev_contador-1) + (((strcontador + "") *cuant).strip("")) +(separador * (rev_contador-1)))
    contador = contador + 1
    rev_contador = rev_contador - 1
    cuant = cuant + 1
    
    if strcontadorer >= 9:
        strcontadorer = 0
        strcontadorer = strcontadorer + 1
        strcontador = str(strcontadorer)
    else:
        strcontadorer = strcontadorer + 1
        strcontador = str(strcontadorer)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que te están pidiendo, es que el código que has creado, hagas funciones que lo queden más limpio y sea más entendible, esto es algo muy común en programación. Te voy a poner un ejemplo intentando modificar lo mínimo posible tu código:

```
#Defino una función
def check_contador(strcontadorer):
    if strcontadorer >= 9:
        strcontadorer = 0
        strcontadorer = strcontadorer + 1
        strcontador = str(strcontadorer)
    else:
        strcontadorer = strcontadorer + 1
        strcontador = str(strcontadorer)
    
    return strcontadorer, strcontador


altura = int(input())
contador = 0
separador = "_"
rev_contador = altura
cuant = 1
strcontadorer = contador
strcontador = str(strcontadorer)


while contador < altura:
    print(separador * (rev_contador-1) + (((strcontador + "") *cuant).strip("")) +(separador * (rev_contador-1)))
    contador = contador + 1
    rev_contador = rev_contador - 1
    cuant = cuant + 1
    
    #Aplico la función en el código
    strcontadorer, strcontador = check_contador(strcontadorer)
```

Se pueden hacer de varias formas el ejercicio, y se pueden crear varias funciones y mejorar el código, yo te he puesto un ejemplo para que entiendas lo que te piden.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por la aclaración me fue de gran ayuda.